HS aged boy, has psychological issues, sees sister or friend beaten by boyfriend
Watched this movie in the late spring on demand but cannot think of the name. I remember it featured a high school aged kid who had some psychological issues. There was always one person who seemed to help him out, a female (sister?). Remember he ended up seeing this female abused by a male in their house/kitchen? 
I think he is close to hurting himself or committing suicide towards the end. It might've been an independent film? Not sure
Almost think there is an object (photo or something) that the boy has and it turns up again in the end.

Any other details you can remember such as language? Time frame the movie was set in (modern era, 1950's, etc)? Every detail helps.

The language is English for sure. As for the setting I think modern era/90s

This sounds like it could be The Perks of Being a Wallflower. The main character has some emotional issues that he deals with throughout the course of the film which leave him on the brink of suicide by the end. There is also a sequence where his sister is hit by her boyfriend.

@A.Still - you should write that up as an answer.

Yes that's it thanks!!

The Perks of Being a Wallflower. The object was likely a mixed tape which was prevalent throughout the film.

The Perks of Being a Wallflower

can you please elaborate on this answer?

You should at leave give credit to the person who provided the answer nine hours before you did in the comments, as opposed to just answering it yourself. Plus, @A.Still provided context as to why this fit your description. You merely wrote the title of the movie as your whole answer.
